# Prepared statements and mysqli_query / mysqli_num_rows?

Tags: php

I am trying to find out how to make my code work with prepared statements. I understood the entire process up to where I commented my code. What do I have to do in order to integrate num_rows and the mysqli_query part properly?

```
function login_check() {

    global $connection;

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE name = $name AND password = $password";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $password); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    // $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rows > 0){
        header('location:../../success.php');
        exit;
    }

    else {
        header('location:../../failed.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**What I tried:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE name = $name AND password = $password";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `name` = ? AND `password` = ?";
```

Adding backticks around table and columns prevents mysql reserved words error.

Remove `$stmt->close()`;

```
if( $stmt->num_rows > 0 ) {
    $stmt->close();
    header('location:../../success.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $stmt->close();
    header('location:../../failed.php');
    exit();
}
```

Adding `$stmt->close()` inside if statement before header is best practice in this case.
Becasue adding it before if statement would result in `$stmt->num_rows` always returning 0; Adding it after the if statment won't work because `exit()` would prefent it from executing.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php):

> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be executed.

Comment: So you mean add it before the if statement? close then if? Thanks for the documentation part.

Comment: @Asperger no inside would be better because `exit()` prefends futher execution of script. So adding it below if statement it won't be executed. And adding it before if statement would prefend `$stmt->num_rows` from having any results so it would always return 0.

Comment: So I  need to add it before my header() not the if. Is close() strictly needed in order to tighten security and prevent leaks?

Comment: " Is close() strictly needed in order to tighten security and prevent leaks?" I can't really give you a suited answer for that. Maybe someone else can. But what I do know is that for example you need 2 querys right after each other and you would close the first the second might not work.

Comment: @Asperger just let me know if you're still having problems